# Posting Values from to PHP Page Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is a file containing HTML and jQuery code to post values to another page (Student Search Results.php) whenever one of the keys entered into a textbox is released.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="JQuery.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Team Search</title>



</head>
<body>

    <form action="Student Search Results.php" method="Post">

    <center>Team Name: <input type="text" name="TeamName" class="search" id="TeamName">  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;              
    Teacher Sponsor: <input type="text" name="Teacher" class="search" id="Teacher"></center><hr>

    </form>

        <script>

$(".search").keyup(function(){

   var Team_Name = $('#TeamName').val();
   var Teacher = $('#Teacher').val();

   var Search_Data = Team_Name + '?????' + Teacher;

   $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Student Search Results.php",
data: {query: Search_Data},
cache: false,
success: function(){
alert('The values were sent');
}
});

});

</script>  


    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the Student Search Results.php page:

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    include "Connection.php";

        $searchData = explode('?????', $_POST['Search_Data']);

        $teamName = $searchData[0];
        $teacher = $searchData[1];

        $query = "SELECT club_table.Club_Name, teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name
            WHERE club_table.Teacher_Email = teacher_user_table.Teacher Email,
            teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name LIKE '%" . $teacher . "%', 
            club_table.Club_Name LIKE '%" . $teamName . "%';";

        mysqli_query($con, $query);

        echo $query;

    ?>

</body>
```

However, $_POST['Search_Data'] is treated as undefined.

Are there any ideas as to why this may be?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a little nitpick from me, make sure you're sanitizing the variables you're passing to your query, prepared statements being preferred. It'll help prevent you from SQL injection attacks if you are pushing this to a production server of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name between brackets in a `$_POST['XXX']`, must be the name with which the value has been posted, in your case `query`.

So you can either:

change the value name in your POST `data` from `query` to `Search_Data` :

```
...
data: {Search_Data: Search_Data},
...
```

or change the index name in the PHP:

```
$searchData = explode('?????', $_POST['query']);
```